# Why the static bool is never set to false?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The first two scripts attached to gameobjects on one scene:

When the game start I want to play the splash screen:
In the script I'm setting the splash flag to true:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadScenes : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        GameControl.splash = true;
        if (!SceneManager.GetSceneByName("The Space Station").IsValid())
        {
            SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(1, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
            StartCoroutine(WaitForSceneLoad(SceneManager.GetSceneByName("The Space Station")));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator WaitForSceneLoad(Scene scene)
    {
        while (!scene.isLoaded)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        SceneManager.SetActiveScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(1));
    }
}
```

When I click/press the escape key it should load back the main menu and it does but I want it to load back the main menu without playing the splash screen again:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadMainMenuOnclick : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Scene scene;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (scene.name != "Menu" && GameControl.player.activeSelf)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(0, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
                StartCoroutine(WaitForSceneLoad(SceneManager.GetSceneByName("Menu")));
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator WaitForSceneLoad(Scene scene)
    {
        while (!scene.isLoaded)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        GameControl.splash = false;
        SceneManager.SetActiveScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(1));
        GameControl.player.SetActive(false);
        Cursor.visible = true;
    }
}
```

This is the GameControl script static class that is not attached to any gameobject. This class is to be able to access variables in two scenes:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public static class GameControl
{
    public static GameObject player;
    public static bool splash;
}
```

And this script that play the splash screens is attached to gameobject on the second scene the main menu scene:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.Assertions.Must;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class Splashes : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Splash Screen")]
    public bool useSplashScreen = true;
    public GameObject splashesContent;
    private List<Graphic> splashes = new List<Graphic>();
    public float splashStayDiration = 3f;
    public float splashCrossFadeTime = 1f;

    void Start()
    {
        if (GameControl.splash == false)
            useSplashScreen = GameControl.splash;
        if (!useSplashScreen || splashesContent.GetComponentsInChildren<Graphic>(true).Length <= 0) return;

        //if we use splash screens and we have splash screens
        #region Get All Splashes
        //if you build on PC Standalone - you can uncomment this
        //foreach (var splash in splashesContent.GetComponentsInChildren<Graphic>(true).Where(splash => splash != splashesContent.GetComponent<Graphic>()))
        //{
        //    splashes.Add(splash);
        //}

        for (var i = 0; i < splashesContent.GetComponentsInChildren<Graphic>(true).Length; i++)
        {
            var splash = splashesContent.GetComponentsInChildren<Graphic>(true)[i];
            if (splash != splashesContent.GetComponent<Graphic>())
            {
                splashes.Add(splash);
            }
        }

        #endregion


        //And starting playing splashes
        StartCoroutine(PlayAllSplashes());

    }

    private IEnumerator PlayAllSplashes()
    {
        //Enabling Splashes root transform
        if (!splashesContent.activeSelf) splashesContent.SetActive(true);

        //main loop for playing
        foreach (var t in splashes)
        {
            t.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            t.canvasRenderer.SetAlpha(0.0f);
            t.CrossFadeAlpha(1, splashCrossFadeTime, false);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(splashStayDiration + splashCrossFadeTime);
            t.CrossFadeAlpha(0, splashCrossFadeTime, false);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(splashCrossFadeTime);
            t.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        //Smooth main menu enabling
        splashesContent.GetComponent<Graphic>().CrossFadeAlpha(0, 0.5f, false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        splashesContent.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            StopCoroutine(PlayAllSplashes());
        }
    }

    public void ExitGame()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

I added two lines:

```
if (GameControl.splash == false)
                useSplashScreen = GameControl.splash;
```

And I used a break point. When running the game it's getting to this lines and splash is true. but when I click/press the escape key it's getting to the check line but splash is still true even if I set it to false in the LoadMainMenuOnclick script.

The splash screen should be playing only when starting the game with the LoadScenes script.

Comment: IMHO returning an IEnumerator with a yield return <nothing> sounds to me as a 'strange' design. You should use tasks or timers.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on all three lines of `while (!scene.isLoaded)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        GameControl.splash = false;` do they **all** get hit?

Comment: @J.vanLangen I take it you are not familiar with Unity3d, that's not a comment that makes sense in the Unity world.

Comment: @mjwills I see now what is the problem. When I hit the escape key it's first going to the Splahes script and make the checking if it's false and only after it it's going to the LoadMainMenuOnclick script and make the lines also the line GameControl.splash = false; so the problem is that it's first going to the Splashes script.

Comment: Found solution for my problem.

Comment: @J.vanLangen Could you show me a sample/example how to do it with my code please ? Not sure how to start changing it. The code is working but maybe I should change the design like you mentioned. Not sure.

Comment: @J.vanLangen `yield return null` puts a coroutine function on hold and is the first thing resumed to (before all other `yield` types). See the [flow chart](https://answers.unity.com/storage/temp/29674-order.png), yield null is between `Update()` and `LateUpdate()`, just before `yield return new WaitForSeconds(...)`. Whereas `yield break` will terminate the coroutine (as if `StopCoroutine()` was called).

Comment: @BenziAvrumi please add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted so that others will know that this is resolved

Comment: @BenziAvrumi As some comments says, i'm not familiar with such structure. I probably can't add any value statement here.